# LED flickers when put into my outside fixtures but incandescent bulb have no problem

Tags: electrical

When I install LED bulbs into my outside fixtures they flicker but when I install incandescent bulbs there is no problems with the light. No flickering at all.

Edit: There's no dimmer, but it has a day / night sensor. The LED is a single bulb with no separate power supply. The flicker slow.

Comment: Is there a dimmer involved?

Comment: we need more information. like is there a dimmer, do LED run from a power supply, flicker slow or rapid

Comment: Try this combination: 1 incandescent and all the rest LED.  Does that flicker?  Tell us more about the switch, motion sensor or day/night sensor that controls them (we're not there, we don't know which).